# Can't see post content when using child theme (wordpress) what is happening?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So basically, when activating the parent theme I am able to click on posts and read them in their entirety on a single page. However, when I activate the child theme, which is functional in every other way, my post content is hidden. I am still able to see all of the content when viewing the source code, as though it is there, but it is not visible to me.

Is there something I'm missing?

Link to page: [Content visible until clicking on the actual post](http://espritduvin.ca/upcoming-events/)

Comment: I would guess the child theme has an empty `single.php` or `entry-*.php` file...

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in style.css file of your child theme. You might have hidden the 'content' class. Please check it. If possible please add your css code.